# How to get the user temp directory in ant

Tags: ant

I can use %tmp% to get the user temp directory in batch file. How can I get the user temp directory in ant?

Answer (score 5):

As a followup to a previous answer, you can access the user's environment variables and use the value from TMP or TEMP:

```
<project name="test" default="showtemp">
  <property environment="env"/>
  <target name="showtemp">
     <echo message="TMP=${env.TMP}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Perhaps a better method would be to use the java system property `java.io.tmpdir`

```
<project name="test" default="showtemp">
   <target name="showtemp">
     <echo message="java.io.tmpdir=${java.io.tmpdir}"/>
   </target>
</project>
```

Comment: `java.io.tempdir` is a really good root to use, it is java's temp directory. In my case I needed to use it to create a named temp directory as the root for a job I was running using ant. This way it is also cross-platform and lets the runner of the task control where the root temp is using the java property `-Djava.io.tmpdir=`

Answer (score 2):

The [tempfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html) task can be used to create temporary files and directories.

Don't forget ANT is a Java program to access to the windows temporary directory would be platform specific. You could try access it using the environment variables:

```
<propety environment="env"/>

<echo message="windows tmpdir=${env.tmp}"/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the standard Java system property `java.io.tmpdir` be the better choice?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Point taken +1. That's much better compared to using the environment variable. Personally I'd use the tempfile task rather than explicitly managing files in the tmpdir.